Change filter context DAX
I am calculating the delay between two steps for each batch in a table 'Batch Tracker'. Important columns include:

Batch: Unique identifier for each batch.

Actual Date: Date on which each step was completed. Has a relationship with DimDate

StepID: Step in the process (e.g., Step 2, Step 6, Step 8).

RC (Root Cause): Reason for delay, if applicable, at specific steps.


My goal is to count the occurrences of each Root Cause impacting delays in Step 8, including those from earlier steps like Step 6.
Currently, my dashboard filters by WeekOfYear (a column in DimDate) based on each step’s Actual Date, so any Root Cause from Step 6 outside the chosen week is excluded. Instead, I need the WeekOfYear filter to consider only the Actual Date of Step 8, which would allow all relevant Root Causes impacting Step 8 to be shown in the report.
Here’s my current DAX code:
CountRC = 
VAR SelectedBatches = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            'Batch Tracker Pivot',
            "Batch", 'Batch Tracker Pivot'[Batch],
            "Actual Date", 'Batch Tracker Pivot'[Actual Date]
        ),
        'Batch Tracker Pivot'[StepID] = 8,
        NOT(ISBLANK('Batch Tracker Pivot'[Actual Date]))
    )
 
VAR AllBatchSteps = 
    CALCULATETABLE(
        'Batch Tracker Pivot', 
        NOT(ISBLANK('Batch Tracker Pivot'[RC]))
    )

VAR DataRC = 
    NATURALLEFTOUTERJOIN(
        SelectedBatches, 
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            AllBatchSteps, 
            "Batch", 'Batch Tracker Pivot'[Batch],
            "RC", 'Batch Tracker Pivot'[RC],
            "StepID", 'Batch Tracker Pivot'[StepID]
        )
    )
 
RETURN 
    COUNTROWS(DataRC)


Tried to join the table with itself, only taking the dates of step 8.

Can you provide some input and expected output ?
